# Как обновить данные JavaFx?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

В TableView использую `ObservableList<Product> productList`.
Чтобы изменить необходимые данные- использую объект из коллекции, но после сохранения ничего не изменяется до тех пор, пока не будет добавлен и удалён элемент. Как с этим бороться?

Объект получаю таким образом:

```
  table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldSelection, newSelection) -> {
    if (newSelection != null) {

        selectedProd=(Product)table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

        //метод(),в котором отпрвляю объект и редактирую его




    }
});
```

Comment: Как вы меняете данные? Какой конкретный объект для списка используете?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman 
добавил

Comment: Дополняйте свой вопрос, вместо публикации комментариев

Comment: @MikhailVaysman+

Comment: table.refresh();

Comment: как вы добавляете данные в таблицу?

Comment: @МихаилКетов Всё в порядке, предыдущий комментарий помог

Answer (score 1):

Если использовать данные типа Property проблема обновления должна решиться для примера:

```
class Product{

   StringProperty testName ;

   public Product(String testName ){
       this.testName = new SimpleStringProperty(testName);
   }

   public StringProperty getTestName() {
       return testName;
   }

   public void setTestName(StringProperty testName) {
      this.testName = testName;
  }
}
```

И уже в контроллере

```
nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getTestName());
```

Если я все правильно помню при редактировании testName автоматически будет обновляться и таблица. И тогда можно обойтись и без table.refresh();